# Chrome extension redirects both tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a simple Chrome extension and it allows me to redirect a site to another one. But in a random website when I click 'Open Link in New Tab' button on that site1.com link, the current and the new tab are both redirecting to the site2.com.

Here's my `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "name",
    "description": "description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "*://*.site1.com/*",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

and `background.js`:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(tab) {
        var getUrl = tab.url,
            splitUrl = getUrl.split("/"),
            title = splitUrl[4],
            url = "https://site2.com/" + title;
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: url});
    },
    {urls: ["*://*.site1.com/*"]},
    ["blocking"]
);
```

It's because `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders` or `chrome.tabs.update(tab.id)`?

Comment: Change the URL itself by returning an object with redirectUrl property as shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), `redirectUrl` was very helful.

Here's the working version.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(tab) {
        var getUrl = tab.url,
            splitUrl = getUrl.split("/"),
            title = splitUrl[4],
            url = "https://site2.com" + title;
        return {
            redirectUrl: url
        };
    },
    {urls: ["*://*.site1.com/*"]},
    ["blocking"]
);
```